# How to OR solr term facets via the search URL in Drupal 7 site?

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-7, faceted-search

I have a Drupal 7 website that is running apachesolr search and is using faceting through the facetapi module.

When I use the facets to narrow my searches, everything works perfectly and I can see the filters being added to the search URL, so I can copy them as links (ready-made narrowed searches) elsewhere on the site.

Here is an example of how the apachesolr URL looks after I select several facets/filters:

```
search_url/search_keyword?f[0]=im_field_tag_term1%3A1&f[1]=im_field_tag_term2%3A100
```

Where the '**search_keyword**' portion is the text I'm searching for and the '**%3A**' is just the url encoded ':' (colon).

Knowing this format, I can create any number of ready-made searches by creating the correct format for the URL.  Perfect!

However, these filters are always ANDed, the same way they are when using the facet interface.  Does anyone know if there is a syntax I can use, specifically in the search URL, to **OR** my filters/facets?  Meaning, to make it such that the result is all entries that contains EITHER of the two filters?

Thanks in advance for any help or pointers in the right direction!

New edit:

I do know how to OR terms within the same vocabulary through the URL, I'm just wondering how to do it for terms in different vocabularies.  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to do this in Drupal

**Enable the fq parameter setting.**

- Go to admin/config/search/apachesolr/[your_search_page]/core_search/edit or just navigate to the settings of the search page you're trying to modify
- Check the 'Allow user input using the URL' setting

**URL Syntax**

- Add the following at the end of the URL: ?fq=tid:(16 OR 38), where 16 and 38 are the term ids

Answer (score 1):

You can write a filter query that looks like:

```
fq=field1:value1 OR field2:value2
```

Alternatively you can use localparams to specify the query operator:

```
fq={!q.op=OR}field1:value1 field2:value2
```

As far as I know, there's not any easier way to do this. There is, in fact, an [rather old bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1223) asking for a way to `OR` the `fq` parameters...

Comment: Hey beerbajay, thanks so much for the response!  I was just wondering, were you saying that this IS indeed something I can include/append to a search URL?  That's what I was asking for... If so, could you give an example of how a search URL with this type of field/filter OR would look like?

Comment: I am not a drupal user, but the examples above are normal url parameters to solr. e.g. `?q=my search word&fq=field1:value1 OR field2:value2`

Comment: Thanks!  It doesn't work quite like that in the URL, but +1 for trying to help!

Comment: If you got it working, add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Of course I would, but I haven't found the solution and suspect I won't be able to do it this way.  It can be done if one builds a custom module, but probably not this easy way I was hoping...